# Cassandra 4 crashes on startup when FIPS mode enabled using BouncyCasle library

Tags: cassandra, bouncycastle, fips

My application runs in FIPS and NO FIPS modes.

NO FIPS mode uses default java.security providers and truststore/keystores are in JKS format.

FIPS mode used BCFKS keystore/truststore format and appropriate change over all systems(changes in java.security providers, cassandra.yaml, ..., restart Cassandra server after changes)

So currently I'm using Cassandra 3 and the plan is upgrade to Cassandra 4.

After upgrading NO FIPS with default settings it works normal. But as soon as I enable FIPS mode it crashes with following message.

```
ERROR [main] 2022-08-19T14:15:58,533 CassandraDaemon.java:911 - Exception encountered during startup
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Failed to initialize SSL
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applySslContext(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1014) ~[apache-cassandra-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyAll(DatabaseDescriptor.java:364) ~[apache-cassandra-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:178) ~[apache-cassandra-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:162) ~[apache-cassandra-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.applyConfig(CassandraDaemon.java:818) [apache-cassandra-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:754) [apache-cassandra-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:889) [apache-cassandra-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to create SSL context using Native transport
        at org.apache.cassandra.security.SSLFactory.validateSslContext(SSLFactory.java:546) ~[apache-cassandra-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applySslContext(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1009) ~[apache-cassandra-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: unable to setup trustmanager
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslServerContext.newSessionContext(ReferenceCountedOpenSslServerContext.java:183) ~[netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslServerContext.<init>(OpenSslServerContext.java:353) ~[netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslServerContext.<init>(OpenSslServerContext.java:334) ~[netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newServerContextInternal(SslContext.java:471) ~[netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:571) ~[netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at org.apache.cassandra.security.SSLFactory.createNettySslContext(SSLFactory.java:339) ~[apache-cassandra-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.security.SSLFactory.validateSslContext(SSLFactory.java:496) ~[apache-cassandra-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applySslContext(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1009) ~[apache-cassandra-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: Failed to load default?trust store
        at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTrustManagerFactorySpi.engineInit(ProvTrustManagerFactorySpi.java:172) ~[bctls-fips-debug-1.0.11.jar:1.0.11]
        at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.init(TrustManagerFactory.java:250) ~[?:1.8.0_321]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslServerContext.newSessionContext(ReferenceCountedOpenSslServerContext.java:147) ~[netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslServerContext.<init>(OpenSslServerContext.java:353) ~[netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslServerContext.<init>(OpenSslServerContext.java:334) ~[netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newServerContextInternal(SslContext.java:471) ~[netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:571) ~[netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at org.apache.cassandra.security.SSLFactory.createNettySslContext(SSLFactory.java:339) ~[apache-cassandra-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.security.SSLFactory.validateSslContext(SSLFactory.java:496) ~[apache-cassandra-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applySslContext(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1009) ~[apache-cassandra-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: BCFKS KeyStore corrupted: MAC calculation failed.
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.ProvBCFKS$BCFIPSKeyStoreSpi.verifyMac(ProvBCFKS.java:945) ~[bc-fips-1.0.2.1.jar:1.0.2.1]
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.ProvBCFKS$BCFIPSKeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(ProvBCFKS.java:1236) ~[bc-fips-1.0.2.1.jar:1.0.2.1]
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445) ~[?:1.8.0_321]
        at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTrustManagerFactorySpi.getDefaultTrustStore(ProvTrustManagerFactorySpi.java:109) ~[bctls-fips-debug-1.0.11.jar:1.0.11]
        at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTrustManagerFactorySpi.engineInit(ProvTrustManagerFactorySpi.java:152) ~[bctls-fips-debug-1.0.11.jar:1.0.11]
        at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.init(TrustManagerFactory.java:250) ~[?:1.8.0_321]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslServerContext.newSessionContext(ReferenceCountedOpenSslServerContext.java:147) ~[netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslServerContext.<init>(OpenSslServerContext.java:353) ~[netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslServerContext.<init>(OpenSslServerContext.java:334) ~[netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newServerContextInternal(SslContext.java:471) ~[netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:571) ~[netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at org.apache.cassandra.security.SSLFactory.createNettySslContext(SSLFactory.java:339) ~[apache-cassandra-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.security.SSLFactory.validateSslContext(SSLFactory.java:496) ~[apache-cassandra-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applySslContext(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1009) ~[apache-cassandra-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        ... 6 more
```

The key error message is

> BCFKS KeyStore corrupted: MAC calculation failed

When you are going to list certificates in keystore (JKS format)you use `keytool --list --keystore PATH`, but for BCFKS format (this is the format used in BouncyCase) you have to pass `--storepass` as well, otherwise you'll get the same message `BCFKS KeyStore corrupted: MAC calculation failed`
Compared with Cassandra 3 version in version 4 SSL content generation goes through netty lib and it seems somewhere in the calls password get lost and I see the same error message `MAC calculation failed`

Related config section from my cassandra.yaml config. Paths and passwords are correct in config.

```
server_encryption_options:
  keystore_password: PASSWORD
  enable_legacy_ssl_storage_port: true
  require_client_auth: false
  internode_encryption: none
  truststore_password: PASSWORD
  keystore: KEYSTORE_PATH
  truststore: TRUSTSTORE_PATH
  store_type: BCFKS
  cipher_suites: [TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
```

Comment: I am trying to run Cassandra 3 in FIPS mode with bouncy castle. Can you please share your config for Cassandra 3 FIPS, I mean the cassandra.yaml, cassandra-env.sh etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra 4 relies on Netty for loading keystore/truststore. In Netty default SSLContent generator is SslProvider.OPENSSL. My used openssl version is FIPS validated and possible it's required to make extra configurations in Netty to allow it use Openssl properly in FIPS mode.

Another solution is to change default SSLProvider.OPENSSL to SSLProvider.JDK allowing Netty rely on JDK SSLContent generator. To do this add following line in cassandra-evn.sh file

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.disable_tcactive_openssl=true"
```