# Where can I find bctls-fips-debug jar?

Tags: maven, url, jar, bouncycastle

I can find [bc-fips-debug](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bc-fips-debug) jar in Maven Central but seems like there is no `bctls-fips-debug` one. This is strange because my google search actually returns some result where this jar is mentioned, such as:

- [this](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/926) GitHub issue
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73437479/cassandra-4-crashes-on-startup-when-fips-mode-enabled-using-bouncycasle-library) Stackoverflow issue

Maybe it was removed from Maven Central, but I can't know for sure. So is it still accessible and if yes, where can I find it?
Thanks!

Tried to search in Maven Central but didn't find.

Comment: If you can get the source code (it's sort of free but not really) you can build your own debug version. As far as I know bouncycastle does not provide such a jar.